# How do I use the php function file_get_contents properly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-get-contents, str-replace

In a nutshell, I am loading a page into a browser and capturing the contents of a div id=content element into a variable named "**contentOrig**". A Javascript based editor loads and a user can modify the contents of the div id=content. The new edits are saved into a variable named "**content**". An ajax request is made when a user clicks a save icon and both the **contentOrig** and **content** variables are passed as HTML to *save.php*.

In the *save.php* file the function **file_get_contents** then opens the original file before it was edited (located in a different directory on the same server instance) and saves the contents of the file as a string into a php variable (**$handle**).  A string replace function ,**str_ireplace()** , is then performed on **$handle** using **$contentOrig** as the search string and **$dataNew** as the replace string. The result should then save as **$contentSave**.

Below are my code files which request and recieve the ajax call. It seems that the str_replace() is not working and the $contentSave variable is not being created.
Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var contentOrig = jQuery.data(content, 'contentOrig', $('#content').html());
alert(contentOrig);
var file_path = $(location).attr('pathname');

bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
var myNicEditor =
    new nicEditor({fullpanel : true, onSave : function(content, id, instance) {
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'https://mydomain.com/admin/save.php',
    data: {"data": content, "filePath" : file_path, "contentOrig" : contentOrig},
    dataType: "html", 
    success: function(data){ 
        alert('Are you sure you want to save this content?');}
      });
} }).panelInstance('content');

});

});
```

*save.php* FILE:

```
<?php

    $site_path = "../publicSite/";
    $admin_site_user = _SERVER["REMOTE_USER"];
    **$dataNew** = $_POST['data'];
    $pagePath = $_POST['filePath']; 
    **$contentOrig** = $_POST['contentOrig'];
    $fileName = str_ireplace("/admin/", $site_path, $pagePath);

    $handle = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $handle2 = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
    **$contentSave = str_ireplace($contentOrig, $dataNew, $handle);**
    $logHandle = fopen('testsave.html','w');

    if($handle2) {
    if (!fwrite($handle2, $contentSave));
    fclose($handle2);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because of `_SERVER` ? Simply `console.log(data)` and you'll see what's happening on the PHP side

Comment: even if I comment out that line that sets $admin_site_user it still does not work.  I know that the string value of $contentSave exist as a string within the string value of $dataNew... I just dont know why its not being found.  Could the fact that the string value has HTML tags be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {"data": content, "filePath" : file_path, "contentOrig" : contentOrig},
```

try

```
data: {data: content, filePath : file_path, contentOrig : contentOrig},
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  This does not make a difference, The data is successfully passed by the ajax call.  It seems that the str_ireplace is just not happening,  I am going to look at the data types of the two variables being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $fileName = str_ireplace("\admin\", $site_path, $pagePath);

I sit two rows away from you dude, you should have just walked over.